# Creo que le he cortado el peluquín a Pikoh

Tags: bug, winterbash, winterbash-2020

Iba yo a comentar en una respuesta, debajo de la cual hay una respuesta de Pikoh, cuando al ir a añadir un comentario me encuentro con que el peluquín de Pikoh se ha duplicado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece ser un bug del Winter Bash, pero lo más importante sería que Pikoh nos asegure que está bien.

Comment: Diría que no se ha dado cuenta, tal vez ha sentido una fresca brisa en la testa, pero de resto seguirá igual, avocado a su trabajo. Regir con puño de hierro en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de [es.so] lo mantiene bastante ocupado.

Comment: Creo que debo tranquilizaros, mi salud capilar esta bien (al menos,no peor que antes del winter bash). Siempre nos quedará Turquía en cualquier caso (aunque no es la [época propicia para ello](https://www.elmundo.es/espana/2020/12/17/5fdb97c4fdddff9db78b479b.html)). Voy a reportar este problema a ver..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto ya ha sido reportado en el sitio principal de meta:

[Hat duplicates when info on a Suggested Edit is expanded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357935/346768)

Asi que solo queda esperar...o tal vez no merezca la pena arreglarlo para algo que dura tan poco. Veremos :)

Edito: tiene la etiqueta [status-planned](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-planned), asi que deduzco que en breve lo repararán.

Comment: Jejeje gracias! Lo importante es que tu salud capilar esté bien, el resto son detalles :)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' lo importante aqui es que para la historia del sitio quedará una publicación que se titula _Creo que le he cortado el peluquín a Pikoh_ No puedo estar mas orgulloso ;)

Comment: Poco se habla de ese gran artilugio, no sé si será por lo de [_Ni hablar del peluquín_](http://origenlenguaje.blogspot.com/2013/11/origen-de-la-expresion-ni-hablar-del.html) ;D En cualquier caso, contento de que te haya gustado, es mucho lo que debemos agradeceros a los moderadores y soy consciente de que a veces pido demasiado así que espero que compense un poco :)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' solo puedo hablar a nivel personal, pero para mi no pides demasiado, al revés, a mi me ayudas mucho y eres muy importante para el mantenimiento del sitio, mas deberías pedir ;) Y aprovechando este emotivo momento, me gustaría desearte a ti y a todos los demás felices fiestas. Hoy me voy de vacaciones y no se lo activo que estaré en el sitio, así que eso que llevo adelantado :)

Comment: ¡Igualmente! Que el 2021 te traiga muchos reportes nuevos ;-D